# how can I get past information on twitter?

Tags: twitter

I need to do some comparison on twitter trends and therefore I need to get past statistics.

for example, how many followers user X had 2 years ago.

Any idea of how to achieve this? or any point to the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can. Haven't been keeping up with twitter much lately but I know there are some sites that track your stats but they only go as far back as when you signed up for the site. Meaning you'd have to keep track of the data yourself and, only in two years could you could see how many followers I had two years ago (today).

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has a list of partner providers on their site that you might want to contact for historical data:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers

Twitter will only return a certain number of recent days in search queries, so the Twitter API isn't too helpful with historical data.